# Find a value in a column and return value of same row but different column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the value "#N/A" through a column and, if it is found, return the value of same row but different column. This is the code I wrote:

```
Sub TestFind()

    Dim r1(), r2()

    r1 = Range("B2:B1000")
    r2 = Range("A2:A1000")

    For i = LBound(r1, 1) To UBound(r1, 1)
        If r1(i, 1) = "#N/A" Then r2(i, 1) 
    Next i

    Range("B3:B1000") = r1

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to loop through cells with error only and use [CVERR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function) function to check error type:

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("B2:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) ' loop through cells with errors
   If cel.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then MsgBox cel.Offset(, -1).Value
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The reason to not use a loop throug the worksheet is that I will have to loop then in a range much bigger than 1000, so it will last a lot. That's why I used a VBA loop instead.

Comment: `SpecialCells` will filter cells with error value only, so you don't need to bother about the range size. Try it!

Comment: And if you already know that all errors are "#N/A" ones then you don't loop at all and just go `MsgBox Range("B2:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Address`!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can use `""N/A` as a real string, you might use `WorksheetFunction.IfError()` or `WorksheetFunction.IfNa()` instead.

Moreover, why don't you use the mentioned functions in a formula (which you put in column `C`, something like:

```
=IfNA(A2;B2)
```

By dragging this formula up till the bottom (row 1000), you might get the same result.